# JAVA SWING-como hacer NO EDITABLES todos los componentes de un jPanel

Tags: java, java-swing, component, jtextfield, jpanel

para empezar queria daros las gracias a todos por escribir sus dudas y a los que responden, ya que me habeis ayudado muchisimo en mi estudio.
mi duda es sobre java swing, vi en este foro como habilitar todos los componentes de un jpanel a la vez:

```
public static void enableComponents(Container container, boolean enable) {
        Component[] components = container.getComponents();
        for (Component component : components) {
            component.setEnabled(enable);
            if (component instanceof Container) {
                enableComponents((Container) component, enable);
            }
        }
    }
```

pero en mi caso no quiero habilitar o deshabilitar (enable) sino hacerlos editables o no (editable) todos a la vez y no encuentro la forma. Tengo un jPanel con labels y jTextField y quiero que no se puedan editar los jTextfield. Gracias!

Comment: xq te complicas la vida ve a la forma grafica le das a las propiedades y lo desactivas y listo. lo unico que puede ser editable son las etiquetas de texto, los desplegables los spinner y las tablas y lo text area con lo cual pues si pones algun componente de eso usas las propiedades y listo

Comment: porque tengo que habilitarlos o deshabilitarlos según se den unas condiciones, así que necesito un metodo para hacerlo por código, y además tengo muchos componentes como para ir uno a uno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola similar al código que escribiste como ejemplo, te dejo este método el cual recibe dos parámetros, el primero es el jpanel donde estarán tus jtextfields y segundo el booleano para el método setEditable.

```
 private void habilitarFields(Component component, boolean b) {
    if (component instanceof JTextField) {
        JTextField txtField = ((JTextField) component);
        txtField.setEditable(b);
    } 
}
```

entonces si quieres que los JTextfields de tu panel(JPanel) no sean editables llamas al método así

```
habilitarFields(panel, false);
```

Comment: Lee [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y asegurate de que tu respuesta incluya la solución a lo que se pregunta. Cualquier respuesta que encamine a los lectores en la dirección correcta ayudará siempre y cuando menciones limitaciones, supuestos, o simplificaciones en tu respuesta. Solo un fragmento de código no es una respuesta.  La brevedad es aceptable pero respuestas robustas son las mejores.

Comment: Millones de gracias!!